# Unable to customize Bootstrap 5 theme colors

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to customize the predefined Bootstrap colors with Sass following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/).

I created a `CustomBootstrap.scss` file with the following contents:

```sass
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$primary: #2c82c9;
```

This should normally override the `$primary` theme color with `#2c82c9`.

> All variables in the `$theme-colors` map are defined as standalone variables.

But the color stays the same when using it like for example: `bg-primary`.

I am using React TypeScript, `"bootstrap": "^5.0.1"`, `"node-sass": "^6.0.0"`, other styles work so everything should be imported correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the variables should be set before the bootstrap `import` that way it overrides them, I use the following setup now.

I have a *_variables.scss* file where I keep my override variables and custom variables.

```scss
// overrides
$primary: #2191fb;

// custom
$success-light: #57cc99;
```

In my *custombs.scss* file I import the variables file and also do the required imports for adding extra custom variables and do the color setting and map merging.

```scss
// import custom variables
@import "./variables";

// required imports
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// set custom colors
$custom-colors: (
    "success-light": $success-light,
);

// merge maps
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
```

I have a *styles.scss* file for my other styling.

```scss
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

And in my *Main.scss* I import all the needed files, with bootstrap at last (I believe this is correct).

```scss
// font
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Newsreader:wght@200;300;500&display=swap");

// styles
@import "./styles";

// bootstrap customization
@import "./custombs";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This way I only need one import in my index file.

```js
import "./styles/Main.scss";
```

I would like some feedback on this setup, if it is correct, better ways... I am new to scss.